# Passing ID to Controller within a Post Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post

I have a function in my VueJs frontend, which passes through an ID to my Controller, in this Controller I want to call a backend function, which takes the ID as an argument.

However, I can't seem to actually receive and store this ID in my Params, does anyone have tips for how I should correctly structure this? I've read the guides, but I can't see exactly how that fits within my small use case. ie my controller is not set up correctly to receive the payload of my Post Request.

Any tips appreciated.

Frontend:

```
  forwardTicketId(ticketId) {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ ticket_id: ticketId }),
  };
  fetch(
    "http://localhost:3000/home/current_ticket_id",
    requestOptions
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
},
```

Outgoing request payload:

```
{
"ticket_id": 85669229421
}
```

Controller:

```
module Panel
  class TicketIdController < HomeController
    def create  # needs id param to be passed in 
      result = Home::UtilityClasses::ActionClass.new(params[:id].to_i).call
      render json: { reply: result }
    end
  end
end
```

Routing:

```
 def draw_ticket_id
   controller: 'ticket_id' do
    get 'current_ticket_id/:id', action: 'create'
  end
end
```

Comment: How does `JSON.stringify({ ticket_id: ticketId })` generate `{"id": 85669229421}`?

Comment: Also, your Rails route is for `get` and the request uses `POST`. Those should probably match each other. The Rails convention is to route `get` to `controller#index`/`controller#show` and `post` to `controller#create`.

Comment: @Stefan This works, thanks, the ID is succesfully being passed as a param, however, the actual contents of Create Method aren't being run, for example, a Puts statement within it, won't print. Could that be related? It has only occurred since these changes. This is without any error being logged also.

Answer (score 0):

This routing definition

```
get 'current_ticket_id/:id', action: 'create'
```

means that the application is expecting the `:id` to be part of the path, not the query body.

That means instead of sending a request to `http://localhost:3000/home/current_ticket_id` and adding the id `85669229421` to the payload, just send the request to this URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/home/current_ticket_id/85669229421
```

I am not sure about the `/home` segment in the URL because the routing definition does say anything about it. But it still might be required because of nesting or generally running the server with a certain folder prefixed.

If in doubt about what routes are available in your application and what they have to look like, you can also run `rails routes` and see a list of all configured routes.

Comment: I recieve the following error in my console ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/home/current_ticket_id/85669229421"):, rails routes is showing that the single route for this controller isn't updating to take account of '/:id'. Any ideas on how to proceed ? Server has been restarted.